# quantmod::chartSeries() in a loop doesn't behave as expected

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

Why is the result an 8-page PDF instead of 1-page PDF with 8 charts?

```
library(quantmod)
s = c("AAL","DAL","UAL","LUV","FDX","ALK","JBLU","HA") 
x <- list()

### get symbols
for (i in s) { x[[i]] <- getSymbols(i, src="yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE, return.class="xts") }

### create pdf
pdf('foo.pdf')
par(mfrow = c( 4, 2 ) )
for (i in x) { chartSeries(i) }
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538151/addsma-not-drawn-on-graph-when-called-from-function and the 3 links in [@GSee's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538151/addsma-not-drawn-on-graph-when-called-from-function#comment18563311_13538394). The problem is that autoprinting does not occur inside functions or loops (and in other situations).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` and `chart_Series` to get multiple charts on 1 page:

```
pdf(file = "charts.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(4,2))
lapply(x,function(x) chart_Series(x))
dev.off()
```

Edit to get ticker symbols:

To put the correct ticker names on the charts you can add the `name` argument to chart_Series like so:

```
name = unlist(strsplit(names(x[[1]])[1],'[.]'))[1]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to get this working ... would you mind writing out the full listing?

Comment: Take the code from the question and substitute the code part starting after the comment line ( „### create pdf“) with the code from the solution.